# Proving the formulas for $\sin 3\theta$ and $\cos 3\theta$. (Check my work.)

Tags: trigonometry

> Substitute in the equation $3\theta=(2\theta+\theta)$, prove that:
>
> a. $\sin 3\theta = 3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$
>
> b. $\cos 3\theta = 4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$

Is this the answer to a)?

$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x,\quad\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2 x$$
\begin{align*}
\sin 3x & = \sin(2x+x)\\
& = \sin 2x \cos x + \cos 2x \sin x\\
& = 2\sin x \cos^2x + (1-2\sin^2 x)\sin x\\
& = 2\sin x - 2\sin^3 x + \sin x - 2\sin^3 x\\
& = 2\sin x - 2\sin^3 x + \sin x - 2\sin^3 x\\
& = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x
\end{align*}

b)
\begin{align*}
\cos 3x & = \cos(2x)\cos(x) - \sin(2x)\sin x\\
        & = (2\cos^2x - 1) \cos x - (2\sin x \cos x) \sin x\\
        & = 2\cos^3x - \cos x - 2\sin x \cos x\\
        & = 2 \cos^3 x - \cos x - 2(1 - \cos^2x) \cos x\\
        & = 2\cos^3x - \cos x- (2\cos x - 2\cos^3x)\\
        & = 4\cos^3x - 3\cos x
\end{align*}

Is b) also correct?

Comment: $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$$ is correct!

Comment: And exercice b)?

Comment: LateX hint : use `\cos` and `\sin` for known functions. (have a look at my edit)

Comment: Lines 4 and 5 are the same, except for that,t he calculation is correct.

Comment: Somebody who is not familiar with this proof might benefit from seeing the substitution of $1 - \sin^2x$ for $\cos^2x$ in the fourth step.

Comment: Going to have a go at exercise b now.

Comment: You made a typographical error in your second proof: In the third line, you meant to write $2\sin^2x\cos x$ in the last term.